# Broken images/css in production mode with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, thin

I'm running a Rails 4 application in production mode...in Windows 8.1...
For some reason y have broken images and css in production mode. Since there is no Passenger gem in Windows, I have to use Apache config to redirect or reverse proxy to **Thin**:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName Depot
    #ServerAlias 

    DocumentRoot "c:/my_directory_tree/depot" 

    <Directory "C:/my_directory_tree/depot">
        Require all granted
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass /depot balancer://depot_cluster/
    ProxyPassReverse /depot balancer://depot_cluster/
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy balancer://depot_cluster>
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001/depot
    </Proxy>

    #ErrorLog  "|C:/Webserver/Apache/bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/example.com/%Y.%m.%d.example.com.error.log 86400" 
    #CustomLog "|C:/Webserver/Apache/bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/example.com/%Y.%m.%d.example.com.access.log 86400" 

combined

</VirtualHost>
```

And run my application with:

```
thin -p 3000 -e production --prefix /depot start -p 3001
```

I already precompiled my assets, but didn't work either.

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Why I'm running in production mode my app? Well... before implementing in a real production server, I need to know how to implement this application in Windows server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To precompile assets for production mode, you need to run

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

answer to the problem was point apache to the public directory

```
<Directory "C:/my_directory_tree/depot/public">
    Require all granted
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

Comment: Yes, I already set  `RAILS_ENV=production`, and then `rake assets:precompile`... from the beginning.

Comment: Please see my update, I have had this error before when I used `url('some-image.png')`. Does any css load?

Comment: I don't get it. Do I have to change all my stylesheets? :/

Comment: If all that is broken is the images, then yes, you need to change `url()` to `image-url()` in all your stylesheets

Comment: Nope, css also is not served properly. Error 404 in all assets

Comment: Interesting, usually you need to give the public folder when deploying apps. Will you try using `<Directory "C:/my_directory_tree/depot/public">`

Comment: It worked, thanks! It is some kind weird to point to that public directory

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad that worked for you :). I edited my answer, would you please mark it as correct?